# Camera and SurfaceView - Video Distorted / Artifacting

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME9Y8.jpg

I have a very specific issue regarding the operation of a SurfaceView and a Camera. I am using the SurfaceView as the preview surface for a camera in an IntentService (to allow background operation).

After a lot of trial and error, I almost have the code working as desired. However, when I am using MediaRecorder to record video, whenever I resume my activity (thus the SurfaceView is re-created) the video is extremely distorted/artifacted in what seems to be rainbow colors with a large black rectangle in the middle. Also the video effect seems to be in a "tile" arrangement. If you look closely, the camera is still working and the video records as normal, but the SurfaceView preview is broken.

Normally, I would re-instantiate the Camera object in the surfaceCreated methods of my SurfaceView callback, but whenever I use Camera.stopPreview(), or several other Camera functions, it causes my MediaRecorder.stop() to hang indefinitely (this is another separate issue). Due to this, I must use the same Camera object in my IntentService when the surface is re-created.

Everything works as normal except this strange video distortion, even the resulting video that the MediaRecorder produces. Only the preview is affected. I am unable to determine whether this is a code issue, software issue, TouchWiz issue, or hardware issue. It occurs in all orientation configurations. Moving the code to surfaceChanged results in the same thing. Thanks in advance for any help or insight into this!

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
if (isRecording) //Only run this code if MediaRecorder is recording
    try {           
        recordingCamera.setPreviewDisplay(rHolder); //This works, but causes the aforementioned distortion
        //recordingCamera.startPreview(); //Removes distortion, but causes MediaRecorder.stop() to freeze app indefinitely          

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //recordingCamera.stopPreview();  //Removes distortion, but causes MediaRecorder.stop() to freeze app indefinitely      

}
```

**Running this on a Galaxy Note II | Android 4.1.2 (TouchWiz)**